# How do you force children elements in a custom panel to a particular size?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, panel

I have a bunch of items in a panel that have the same height. I want the items in the panel to shrink their width based on the max width of the panel itself.

Eg - Width of the panel is 400, you have 4 items in the panel, each item gets a width of 100. If it were 2 items, each item would be 200 width.

After calling `child.Measure` the second time with the expect width of the item, the `child.DesiredSize` changes to something else entirely. How do I force the item to take the Width I'm giving it?

```
public class DynamicShrinkPanel : StackPanel
{
    public DynamicShrinkPanel()
    {
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        Size desiredSize = new Size();
        foreach (UIElement child in InternalChildren)
        {
            // First call to get the desired size.
            child.Measure(constraint);
            double properChildWidth = constraint.Width / InternalChildren.Count;
            // Second call to set what I want, doesn't do what I expect
            child.Measure(new Size(properChildWidth, child.DesiredSize.Height));
            desiredSize.Height = child.DesiredSize.Height;
            desiredSize.Width += child.DesiredSize.Width;
        }

        return desiredSize;
    }
}
```

Comment: sounds like you can use `UniformGrid` with `Rows="1"`

Comment: Right, don't write a custom Panel for this. Use a UniformGrid instead.

Comment: UniformGrid doesn't take up the full width of the control it's nested in automatically. So in my case if the available width is 500, it's going to use all 500 no matter how many or few items you put in it. Uniform grid seems to only take up as little space as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, don't use `MeassureOverride` to calculate the exact size but rather the `ArrangeOverride` method.

```
protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
{
     Size desiredSize = new Size();
     foreach (UIElement child in InternalChildren)
     {
         child.Measure(constraint);
         desiredSize.Height = child.DesiredSize.Height;
         desiredSize.Width = constraint.Width;
     }

     return desiredSize;
 }

 protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
  {
        double offset = 0;
        double properWidth = arrangeSize.Width / InternalChildren.Count;
        foreach (UIElement child in InternalChildren)
        {
             child.Arrange(new Rect(offset, 0, properWidth, arrangeSize.Height));
             offset += properWidth;
        }

        return arrangeSize;
    }
```